# Qual a diferença entre $_GET e $_POST?

Tags: php, post, get

Poderiam explicar detalhadamente o que são? E também dar exemplos de como funcionam?

Comment: Relacionada (ou duplicada): [Uso de $_REQUEST ao invés de $_GET, $_POST e $_COOKIE](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/37114/18246)

Comment: Relacionada: [É seguro usar $_GET no PHP? (Parâmetro na URL)](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/71978/18246)

Comment: O problema dessas perguntas relacionadas é o título. Nunca eu ia achar isso, mas tudo bem. Obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: **Bem** relacionada: [Quais as vantagens de se utilizar os métodos HTTP corretos?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/49322/18246)

Comment: **Bem** relacionada: [Como o protocolo HTTP processa as requisições?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/174116/18246)

Comment: Sim, Lucas. É quase impossível achar algo na busca do site, eu entendo bem.

Comment: Eu não negativei a pergunta, no entanto pela **baixa qualidade da resposta** que recebeu as perguntas que linkei respondem bem melhor, GET e POST não é questão de visibilidade, tanto que o POST pode receber diferentes tipos de dados no payload, a diferença é muito maior.

Comment: A unica diferença entre os 2 é que não aparece na URL? Testando aqui parece que somente é isso..

Comment: @LucasCarvalho isto só em navegadores, o protocolo HTTP vai muito além de navegadores, se usar em um chamada via Java em um aplicativo android, ambos serão invisíveis. A diferença entre POST e GET é na maneira que transmite os dados, lembre-se POST pode receber mais de um tipo de formato de dados (payload), veja esta resposta: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/50989/3635, depois detalho mais sobre os formatos

Comment: Muito obrigado, Guilherme!!

Comment: No form, o method="POST" e method="post" tem diferença?

Comment: @LucasCarvalho não tem diferença, ambos são iguais, o navegador trata tudo para corrigir e evitar problemas até mesmo `method="PoSt"` vai funcionar

Answer (score 1):

A grande diferença entre os métodos GET e POST provavelmente é a visibilidade. Uma requisição GET é enviada como string anexada a URL, enquanto que a requisição POST é encapsulada junto ao corpo da requisição HTTP e não pode ser vista